# WPF RibbonRadioButton not entirely clickable

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `RibbonRadioButton` inside a `RibbonMenuButton`.
My problem is that only the orange part (the label part) is clickable.
If I click on the yellow part, the ribbon menu closes but the radio is not checked.
Same problem with `PreviewMouseDown` Event !

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxkBa.png) of `RibbonRadioButton`.

Here is the XAML code :

```
<ribbon:RibbonMenuButton ToolTip="Interaction" LargeImageSource="Images/measures.png">
    <ribbon:RibbonRadioButton Label="Manip 3D" GroupName="CartoInteraction" IsChecked="{Binding ...}" PreviewMouseDown="MyFunc" />
    <ribbon:RibbonRadioButton Label="Points" GroupName="CartoInteraction" IsChecked="{Binding ...}" PreviewMouseDown="MyFunc" />
    <ribbon:RibbonRadioButton Label="Distances" GroupName="CartoInteraction" IsChecked="{Binding ...}" PreviewMouseDown="MyFunc" />
</ribbon:RibbonMenuButton>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried juggling with Templates and Styles, but it was way too complicated.

It seems the good way is to use `RibbonMenuItem` (yes, I know, sounds logical) that can act as checkable by setting `IsCheckable="True"`. Then, you lose the `GroupName` property of your `RibbonRadioButton`, but the Binding do the job.

Here is the finale code :

```
<ribbon:RibbonMenuButton ToolTip="Interaction" LargeImageSource="Images/measures.png" Style="{x:Null}">
   <ribbon:RibbonMenuItem Header="Manip 3D" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding ...}" />
   <ribbon:RibbonMenuItem Header="Points" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding ...}" />
   <ribbon:RibbonMenuItem Header="Distances" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding ...}" />
</ribbon:RibbonMenuButton>
```

O